# What is the purpose of "The Harbour" in Hell Yeah: Wrath of the Dead Rabbit?

Tags: hell-yeah

I recently got access to "The Island" in Hell Yeah: Wrath of the Dead Rabbit. When I assign workers to tasks, one of them is The Harbour. What is the reward for sending the workers hear since it gives a poor description?

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got something from the Harbour. It apparently gives free customizations as opposed to buying them from the shop.